# Breakpoints still fire in Release mode of the XCode 5.5.1 build schema for IOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I am used to creating a Release schema for OSX applications, whereby I switch build mode to Release, and set the debugger to None. This removes the breakpoint info from the app and optimises it.

Although I can set the Release mode for the IOS applications, there is no way to set the debugger to None. And, it occurs that in the Release mode the breakpoints are still honored by XCode 5.5.1, which tells me that the debug info is still compiled into the app.

How can I make sure that my IOS app is as pristine as possible, and does not have debug info, and does not fire the breakpoints in Xcode, while running on the device?

Thanks.

EDIT: Solution is to set "Generate Debug Symbols" to No in Release build.

Answer (score 1):

Having breakpoints enabled (or not) doesn't change the size of your code.  Your Release scheme should be setting "Optimization Level" -Os, "Symbols Hidden by Default" to Yes and "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" to Yes.  All of these are default options in new projects, so you really shouldn't have to change anything.

Even in a release build, breakpoints will still function because the symbolic information is stored separately from the built product.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out my default Release build had "Generate Debug Symbols" set to Yes. Although "Strip debug symbols during copy" and "Symbols hidden by default" were set to Yes, it did not prevent the breakpoints from firing.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confused on breakpoints vs debugging symbols.  Your release build by default should remove debugging symbols from the final product.  However that doesn't stop you from attaching a debugger to it.  You can hook a debugger up to any app you want (mostly true), however if the debugging symbols are striped then all you'll be able to see is the assembly instructions.  This is what you see when you try to step into Apples frameworks from your own code.